# Git submodule commit hooks

Tags: git, git-submodules, pre-commit-hook

I'm using a git submodule (let's call it SubmoduleRepo) so that I can include my module in couple of projects.

I can commit to SubmoduleRepo from any project that uses it.

I can update, commit and push to SubmoduleRepo pretty hassle-free.

I need to execute a commit hook whenever I commit something while working in a directory in a project that contains the SubmoduleRepo (when I work in SubmoduleRepo, the commit hook executes as expected)

There is no .git folder in submodule's dir (only .git file that specifies path to current directory).

Comment: This is an old question, but possibly you should assign the correct answer to either yourself or Jason. :)

Answer (score 38):

If you have Git 2.10+ you can get the `hooks` directory by running:

```
`git rev-parse --git-path hooks`
```

Note: by default it is `.git/hooks` but if you are in a submodule it will be different.

Pre Git 2.10+ you would want something like:

```
`git rev-parse --git-dir`/hooks
```

More info at:
[Find path to git hooks directory on the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073053/find-path-to-git-hooks-directory-on-the-shell)

Answer (score 28):

I've found solution couple of moments after posting this...

You can put hooks in .git/modules//hooks/ - eg. .git/modules/web/js/modules/rate if your submodule is located in /web/js/modules/rate directory.

Comment: This is unfortunately not scriptable.

Comment: This is scriptable with `git rev-parse --git-dir`. See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073053/find-path-to-git-hooks-directory-on-the-shell