# Find path to git hooks directory on the shell

Tags: git

How do I find the full path to the `.git/hooks` directory of the current Git repository?

---

I see the following issues:

### Deep in the directory structure

I may be anywhere deep in the git repository directory structure, e.g.

```
/home/user/project/.git/hooks
```

and I am in folder

```
/home/user/project/foo/bar/baz/
```

### Submodules

Newer git versions put submodule meta data not into `.git/` but in the main repository and `.git` is only a file, e.g.

```
$ cat /home/user/project/vendor/foo/.git
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/vendor/foo
```

So in this case, the hooks dir is in

```
/home/user/project/.git/modules/vendor/foo/hooks
```

Comment: At least for the parent repo (not sure yet for the submodules), make sure to check `git config core.hooksPath` with git 2.9 (June 2016) or more. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37293090/6309)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `git rev-parse --git-dir` to get the path to the repository used for your current directory.  This will deal with gitlinks (using a file in place of the `.git` directory) as well as having use of the `$GIT_DIR` environment variable.  The hooks directory will always be inside of that so you can use:

```
`git rev-parse --git-dir`/hooks
```

to get the path to the hooks directory.

This is documented in the [git rev-parse manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)

Comment: can this be used with `git submodule foreach`? for instance, something like `git submodule foreach cp .git/hooks/commit-msg $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/hooks`? the problem i'm seeing is that since shell expands the git rev-parse first, it evaluates to the git-dir of the superproject.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow that would probably be better addressed as a new question rather than a comment, since comments here are quite limited in length and formatting capabilities. But have you tried placing single quotes around everything after `foreach`? That should delay evaluation as needed.

Comment: that worked (although i also had a different problem)! thank you.

Comment: This is no longer correct, use `git rev-parse --git-path hooks/hook-name` to find where a hook is stored.

Answer (score 26):

Starting git 2.9 (June 2016), you will need to look at the new config `core.hooksPath` to really be sure of the hooks folder.

`git rev-parse --git-dir`/hooks won't be enough anymore.

See [commit 867ad08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/867ad08a2610526edb5723804723d371136fc643), [commit de0824e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de0824ed8fa3319cfdc0c79c06c06d7c72c6adc6), [commit bf7d977](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf7d977f8c9a01b4decab2ecbd1ba02203e5a8bc), [commit 49fa52f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49fa52fd003ece5ea997607167bc5aaec3ff61af) (04 May 2016) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6675f50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6675f501f6b987dbdb0dbeb1d2efeb5a27fc41a7), 17 May 2016)</sup>

So make sure you check if `git config core.hooksPath` is defined or not, as it will override the default hooks folder location.

The [`git config` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/867ad08a2610526edb5723804723d371136fc643/Documentation/config.txt) now includes:

```
core.hooksPath
```

> By default Git will look for your hooks in the '`$GIT_DIR/hooks`' directory.
>   Set this to different path, e.g. '`/etc/git/hooks`', and Git will try to find your hooks in that directory, e.g. '`/etc/git/hooks/pre-receive`' instead of in '`$GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-receive`'.
>
> **The path can be either absolute or relative. A relative path is taken as relative to the directory where the hooks are run**.

---

Git 2.10 (Q3 2016) uses that new `core.hooksPath` setting.

So to get the **effective** `hooks` path, you need to run:

```
git rev-parse --git-path hooks
```

From the `git rev-parse` [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse---git-pathltpathgt):

```
--git-path <path>
    Resolve "$GIT_DIR/<path>" and takes other path relocation variables such
    as $GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY, $GIT_INDEX_FILE... into account. For example,
    if $GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY is set to /foo/bar then "git rev-parse
    --git-path objects/abc" returns /foo/bar/abc.
```

See [commit 9445b49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9445b4921e3e996b2d38d58c594f95d63a72dcea) (16 Aug 2016) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d05d0e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d05d0e99665ecb67c3e8b9b3be40b12e9052a8b8), 19 Aug 2016)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `--git-dir` you can also use the following to find the root of a git repository since this is more generic, I am just adding it here for completion:

```
echo $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

Then append `/.git/hooks` to it? I haven't tried it with sub-modules though.

Comment: This won't really help for submodules.

Answer (score 5):

if you are in a project directory
you can know the current hooks path by typing to terminal

```
git config core.hooksPath
```

if the value is empty then you can set the path to your .githooks folder
you can do that by typing this command

```
git config core.hooksPath .githooks/
```

you'll find now that hooks path changed and you can confirm by first command again.

Comment: git config core.hooksPath .git/hooks