# Programmatically get path to git directory in bash (including submodules)

Tags: git, bash, git-submodules

Is it possible to programmatically find the path to the .git directory including for submodules?

I'm trying to write a script that installs a git hook but I can't find a straightforward way to find the .git directory for the project. Ideally it should cover the following cases:

1. In root directory of project
2. In sub-directory of project
3. In root directory of submodule within project
4. In sub-directory of submodule within project

I could do all of this manually but I'd rather not parse the .git file of a submodule.

Edit: I'd be interested in a solution in python as well.

Comment: howabout using `find` to search for the `.git` directory?

Comment: @Fredrik how would you know how many directories to go up? Also what if there is a directory with the exact same name?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073053/find-path-to-git-hooks-directory-on-the-shell

Comment: @qqx thanks! That didn't come up when googling. Although http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848191/git-submodule-commit-hooks did

Comment: This question is still first in Google, so copying the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073053/find-path-to-git-hooks-directory-on-the-shell solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rev-parse --git-dir` seems to be what you want. I just tested it with a submodule:

```
cd mymodule
git rev-parse --git-dir  # --> .git
git submodule add ssh://.../path/to/mysubmodule
cd mysubmodule
git rev-parse --git-dir  # --> /home/.../mymodule/.git/modules/mysubmodule
```

This surprised me, since there was a `.git` in `mysubmodule`, but it turned out to be a file, with the following contents:

```
gitdir: ../.git/modules/mysubmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command) SO question uses `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to find the top directory.

Comment: That doesn't give you the .git directory