# React Setup: Git submodule is ignored by Husky - 6.0.0

Tags: reactjs, git, next.js, git-submodules, husky

I have a React project named `x-y-z` which has a private remote repo.
Inside this project, I have another project named `a-b-c` which is a `git submodule`.

I am using [Husky: v6.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) and have set up a `pre-commit` hook.
The `pre-commit` hook is working fine for the parent project (`x-y-z`), but it is not working for the submodule project (`a-b-c`).

I cannot figure out anything. Can anyone please suggest a workaround?

**pre-commit**

```bash
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run pre-commit
```

**pre-commit script**

```js
"pre-commit": "lint-staged",
```

**lint-staged config**

```js
module.exports = {
  '*.(js|jsx)': ['npm run prettify', 'npm run lint'],
  '*.(html|css|scss|json)': ['npm run prettify'],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodules are separate repositories, hooks in the superproject don't work in submodules. You need to install and configure the hook [into all the submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848371/7976758) where you want the hook to work.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up. Yes, that ia correct - submodules are separate repositories. But, I just want to know, how can we use or apply the parents configs to them. For not only one user, but all of them.

Comment: @AniketKolekar No way, sorry. Git doesn't have a concept of "parent config". As separate repositories submodules have their own config files and global config files, that's all.