# Add pre commit hook to submodule from parent module's .git

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

So I have a project with a submodule that gets updated every once in awhile. I have some rules for commits that I try to follow and one of them is to include the branchname in the commit. I accomplish this with githooks as follows:

From top level directory

**.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg**

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH=`git branch | grep '^\*' | cut -b3-`
FILE=`cat "$1"`
echo "$BRANCH $FILE" > "$1"
```

**.git/hooks/pre-commit**

```
#!/bin/bash

find vendor -name ".git*" -type d | while read i
do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                DIR=`dirname $i`
                rm -fR $i
                git rm -r --cached $DIR > /dev/null 2>&1
                git add $DIR > /dev/null 2>&1
        fi
done
```

Then I just set permissions
sudo chmod 755 .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
sudo chmod 755 .git/hooks/pre-commit

However, this does not work for the submodule as it does not have the .git directory. Is there a way to force the submodule to use the hook from the parent directory? If I open the submodule independently I can make it work however, it's alot more practical to keep it under the parent as it keeps stuff organized.

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67848922/7976758 2. Submodules have `.git` directory; but you have to understand submodules are separate repositories and have separate hooks.

Comment: Not for the repo I'm in:

from partent repo cd submodule
ls -lah
.rw-r--r--    28 uname  7 Oct DATE  .git

if i clone the submodule separately I can edit it (as I mentioned in the question)

Comment: I'd be totally down to add the hooks to the submodule but I can't do it when it's attached to the parent module and created by git submodule update --init as the submodule dosen't have a .git directory, just a file.


When submod is independent:
`drwxrwxr-x     - user 20 Oct DATE  .git`


When submod is attached to parent and created by git submodule update:
`.rw-r--r-- 28 uname 7 Oct DATE .git`

Comment: Read the `.git` file: it contains the path to the submodule repository. Look there: it's a repository, with a `hooks` directory. You can put Git hooks here. It's all kind of painful though. Using `git rev-parse --git-directory` will help you automate this if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 3):

With a submodule, you can either have a separate Git directory, or you can have an absorbed submodule.  The latter is preferred these days by the Git code, and when one is in use, `.git` in the submodule is a special file called a *gitlink*, which points to a directory in the main repository's `.git` directory.

If you want to find the hooks directory for any Git repository, whether a submodule or not, you can run this command:

```
$ git rev-parse --git-path hooks
```

That will print the hooks directory.  If you want to use the same hooks in the submodule as for the parent, you can make the submodule's hooks directory a symlink to the parent's.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. I had to: `vim .git/modules/submodule/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`, `vim .git/modules/submodule/hooks/pre-commit`.

Thanks.